# Number format exception Converting Zero string to integer

Tags: java

I want to read some values from properties file

like that 
SPAN_NUMBER=2
when I get the span_number, I have to convert it into integer.

```
try { int   i=Integer.parseInt(rsBundle.getString("SPAN_NUMBER"));
            }catch(Exception e) {
                i=0;
            }
```

It working successfully.

But in case if SPAN_NUMBER=0(Zero), it will throw number format exception.

I have to pass this number as integer  somewhere.
When I pass hardcode value as '0'. It will run successfully.
But I want to pass this value from properties file.
Help me !

Comment: please provide the code for more help

Comment: I guess the `rsBundle.getString` has something to it that returns `null` or something else when the value is `0`. Just add a check for this and you're done.

Comment: You can debug your application to see that rsBundle.getString("SPAN_NUMBER") is eventually evaluating to

Comment: Set the `i` variable outside the try and catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove anything besides a number in the string then parse it

```
String string = rsBundle.getString("SPAN_NUMBER");
if(string != null) {
    string = string.replaceAll("\\D","");
    if(string.length()==0) string="0";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```

Comment: Yes It works successfully but tell me what u have replaced in string.i didn't understand.

Comment: @PrashantAggarwal "\\D" replaces everything that is not a number.